# Get HTML for all class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get all the html of a class name where the class names are used more than once

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
    $("span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext").each(function() {
        alert(this.html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
alert(this.innerHTML);
```

or

```
alert($(this).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext").each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).html()` not `this.html()` also give space between

`span.feeditemtext` and `.cxfeeditemtext` in your selector

`$("span.feeditemtext.cxfeeditemtext")`

like this:

```
$("span.feeditemtext .cxfeeditemtext").each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

**SEE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/wHVdN/5/